# How to submit nib files to perforce that were previously added?

Tags: macos, perforce, nib

Recently I added a .bundle file that had several .nib files in it to perforce.  I'm new to using p4 on a mac so I didn't think much of it and it submitted just fine.

I now tried to check out and edit the bundle (basically just replace the previous version with a new one) and when I try to check it in I get the error -

> read:
> /devdir/Resources.bundle/CreateAccount.nib:
> Is a directory
>
> Submit aborted -- fix problems then use 'p4 submit -c 82488'. Some
> file(s) could not be transferred from client.

I don't understand why it let me add it in the first place if this is the case but that aside I'm not sure what to do about it now.  The files are just sitting in this limbo state in a pending change list.

Is there any way to force submit them or delete them (I could just readd the whole bundle in that case)?  Or any other suggestions..

Thanks

Comment: And what is ' /devdir/Resources.bundle/CreateAccount.nib' on your machine? Is it a file? Is it a directory? Is it something else, like a symbolic link or something odd like that?

Comment: /devdir/ is just the directory path. Resources.bundle is the bundle file. I think they are most similar to zip files. CreateAccount.nib is a file that holds information about an interface form. A nib file is also a kind of container file and from the gui it looks like a single file but is really a directory.

Comment: I haven't found much on how to add .bundle files (thus the question).  I looked around on how to add .nib files though and most people do not add them directly to perforce.   This just seems to be an issue with these types of files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OS X, `.nib` and `.bundle` "files" are both actually directories with extensions in their names.  As such, in Perforce, you will need to add/edit the contents, not the items themselves.

For example:

```
p4 reconcile /devdir/Resources.bundle/CreateAccount.nib/...
```

or

```
p4 edit /devdir/Resrources.bundle/CreateAccount.nib/...
p4 submit /devdir/Resrources.bundle/CreateAccount.nib/...
```

If you're editing inside of `Xcode`, or an external editor (or getting updated files from somebody else), I'd suggest using `p4 reconcile` to let Perforce determine which of the contents need to be updated.

Generally, in OS X and iOS development this isn't necessary since you would not have `.nib` files these days (`.xib` files, which are XML-based are the *source* to `.nib` files in modern `Xcode` development).   However, if you get code from a third party, they often have already-compiled resources.